# Get the exit code of a ProcessHandle in Java 10

Tags: java, process

In Java 10, it seems to be impossible to get the exit code of a process referenced by a ProcessHandle after calling onExit whereas we can get it from a Process.

Do you confirm?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is right. You can obtain an exit code of a process only if you created it yourself

Comment: This causes problems for forked processes, even if you create it.